# How can I send a message to a whatsapp group using chat-api

Tags: whatsapp

Hello Im using this library (https://github.com/chatapi/whatsApp-php) to send messages by whatssapp. I see the client object has the following methods:

```
[0] => getInstance
[1] => sendMessage
[2] => getMessages
[3] => getStatus
[4] => getQrCode
[5] => createGroup
[6] => sendFile
[7] => setWebHook
[8] => getWebHook
[9] => logout
[10] => reboot
[11] => getMessagesQueue
[12] => clearMessagesQueue
```

The question is: How can I send a message to an exist group? is it possible at all using this library?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the php api isn't full.

Using raw http api you can send `dialogs` request, find the group `chatId`, and send it to `sendMessage` request.